# Generate route templates from URL using ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

I've been reading about URL generation based on values in a route dictionary.

```
app.Run(async (context) =>
{
    var dictionary = new RouteValueDictionary
    {
        { "operation", "create" },
        { "id", 123}
    };

    var vpc = new VirtualPathContext(context, null, dictionary, 
        "Track Package Route");
    var path = routes.GetVirtualPath(vpc).VirtualPath;

    context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Menu<hr/>");
    await context.Response.WriteAsync(
        $"<a href='{path}'>Create Package 123</a><br/>");
});
```

Is it possible to perform the reverse action and generate a route template from a URL?  I would think ASP.NET core would need to do this in order to check an incoming request URL to see if it matches a route in the route table in middleware.  So if a route was mapped using say "/package/{operation}/{id}", it would have to have some mechanism to see that the URL "/package/create/123" matches this route.

I have a need to perform this type of action to see if a URL matches a custom route template that I have stored in the database when a request comes in.